# Jmeter/Ant test run fails with "Fatal error during transformation"

Tags: ant, jmeter

I've been following the instructions in the Jmeter Ant Task, but I keep on getting the following error:

```
Buildfile: C:\Users\Chris Gill\apache-jmeter-3.1\extras\build.xml

run:
     [echo] funcMode = false
   [jmeter] Executing test plan: C:\Users\Chris Gill\apache-jmeter-3.1\Tests\Test.jmx ==> C:\Users\Chris Gill\apache-jmeter-3.1\Tests\Test.jtl

_message_xalan:

xslt-report:
     [xslt] Processing C:\Users\Chris Gill\apache-jmeter-3.1\Tests\Test.jtl to C:\Users\Chris Gill\apache-jmeter-3.1\Tests\Test.html
 [xslt] Loading stylesheet C:\Users\Chris Gill\apache-jmeter-3.1\extras\jmeter-results-report_21.xsl
 [xslt] C:\Users\Chris Gill\apache-jmeter-3.1\Tests\Test.jtl:1:1: Fatal Error! Premature end of file.
 [xslt] Failed to process C:\Users\Chris Gill\apache-jmeter-3.1\Tests\Test.jtl

BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\Chris Gill\apache-jmeter-3.1\extras\build.xml:124: Fatal error during transformation using C:\Users\Chris Gill\apache-jmeter-3.1\extras\jmeter-results-report_21.xsl: Premature end of file.; SystemID: file:/C:/Users/Chris%20Gill/apache-jmeter-3.1/Tests/Test.jtl; Line#: 1; Column#: 1
```

I've been searching for solutions and have tried reinstalling Ant and Jmeter, then going through the instructions again, but I still get the same result.

I made the changes to my build.xml file as follows:
[image]

[image]

Is there something I've done wrong in my build.xml file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are getting means that your `Test.jtl` file is not a valid XML file, so I would suggest the following validations:

1. Inspect `C:\Users\Chris Gill\apache-jmeter-3.1\Tests\Test.jtl` file, it should be a valid XML file ending with `</testResults>`. At this point you should be able to see what's wrong.
2. Make sure you have the following line in `build.xml` file:

   ```
   <property name="jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format" value="xml"/>
   ```
3. You can also add the next line to the `build.xml` file:

   ```
   <jmeter
       jmeterhome="${jmeter.home}"
       testplan ="${testpath}/${test}.jmx"
       resultlog="${testpath}/${test}.jtl"
       jmeterlogfile="/path/to/jmeter.log"> <!-- enable JMeter log -->
   ```

   After test execution you will be able to see the log file in the defined location with all the troubleshooting information available

References:

- [JMeter Ant Task](http://www.programmerplanet.org/projects/jmeter-ant-task/)
- [Five Ways To Launch a JMeter Test without Using the JMeter GUI](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui)

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. I changed the output from the test plan to an xml file and now it works perfectly.